# Start Django project and open Visual Studio Code using batch file

Tags: python, django, batch-file, command-line

I want to create a batch file where I can start a Django project and open visual studio code at the same time while creating a new file inside the terminal command (Window 10). This is how it goes when I want to start a Django project:

**Command:**

```
>C:\Users\bvsia\Documents\Programming\Python\Django
>django-admin startproject mysite
>cd mysite
>python manage.py startapp main
>python manage.py runserver
```

then I open Visual Studio Code from the terminal command typing `code .` on the file that was created. Then I will have my Django project to work on.

I want the one click file for all what I did step by step. This is what I got so far in batch file.

```
@echo off
start cmd.exe /C "django-admin startproject mysite && cd mysite && python manage.py startapp main && python manage.py runserver && cd C:\Users\bvsia\Documents\Programming\Python\Django"
start cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\bvsia\Documents\Programming\Python\Django && code ."
start http://127.0.0.1:8000/
```

I have tried several ways to execute this but nothing worked. I hope you can see what I am trying to do here and help me with this. Thanks

EDIT: The only output was having the local host http://127.0.0.1:8000/ open but Django was not working nor opening Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You have not specified what is not working or if there is any output or errors that you are getting.

Comment: Sorry. The only output was having the local host http://127.0.0.1:8000/ open but Django is not working nor Visual Studio Code.

Comment: You are using `CMD.exe` to launch a bunch of commands.  It will act no differently then if all the commands were on separate lines.  The next command in the chain will not process until the previous command completes and closes itself.